# Getting a .gif to display through JPanel?

Tags: java, image, jpanel, display

I've been trying to open an image through through this class implementing JPanel. Why won't my code display the image? It compiles, runs, opens Java, and then closes it.

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class ImagePanel extends JPanel{

private ImageIcon coin;

public ImagePanel(){
    ImageIcon coin = new ImageIcon("coin.gif");
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    int x = 5;
    int y = 10;
    if(coin != null)
        coin.paintIcon(this, g, x, y);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    ImagePanel window = new ImagePanel();
    window.setBounds(100, 100, 395, 355);       
    window.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You class extends `JPanel` which is a `JComponent`.

In order to show your `JComponent` you need to attach it to a `JFrame`.

You chould change your `main` to

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ImagePanel window = new ImagePanel();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 395, 355);
    frame.setContentPane(window);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```